# Add nfc tag listener in NFC enabled Android application with PhoneGap

Tags: android, events, cordova, nfc

I am writing an application for read the mifare card from my native android application.For this purpose I am using phonegap 1.9.0.

I have added the phonegap-nfc plugins.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-nfc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function onLoad() 
{
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() 
{
    // Here I want to write my code for tag listener.

}
```

Now In [phonegap blog](http://www.phonegap.com/2011/09/26/building-an-nfc-enabled-android-application-with-phonegap/),they are discussing about **adding a nfc tag listener**.

But it is not fully clear.So please tell me how to add event listener in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all right there in the blog post. For example:

```
nfc.addNdefListener(
function() {
    document.write("Found an NDEF formatted tag");
},
function() {
    console.log("Success.");
},
function() {
    console.log("Fail.");
}
```

Comment: all PG commands must be done after you get the deviceready event.

Comment: Hi Simon,Thank for the answer.Now my Nexus phone able to detect the nfc tag.Now can you tell me how to read particular sector from it.

Comment: @vikky sorry, I don't have a NFC capable phone so I actually haven't used the plugin.